# Automatically resize list boxes when resizing a form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Form with two list boxes on it.  Also there is a label on top of each of them

```
listbox1
|      |
|      |
|______|

listbox2
|      |
|      |
|______|
```

When the user resizes the form (for example maximizes it), I would like the list boxes to automatically expand in height:

```
listbox1
|      |
|      |
|      |
|      |
|______|

listbox2
|      |
|      |
|      |
|      |
|______|
```

Comment: Ups in edit mode it looks nicer :)

Comment: you could use the controls dock property to determine position relative to the size of the form.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The listbox's 'Anchor' property is set to Top, Left by default. Select Bottom and Right as well and it will now resize.

However, I see that you have two listboxes (stacked on top of eachother), so the above suggestion will not get them both to resize evenly in a vertical manner. But it will solve the resizing horizontally for you.

In order to get both to resize vertically, you may need to use a grid splitter, and manually determine the correct position.